# azure portal subscription filter jumps to settings

Tags: azure, azureportal

On the Azure portal, since a couple of days, clicking on the subscription filter, the portal automatically brings me to directory/subscription settings. This is not the desired behaviour.
[image: when I click]

I automatically get this :

[image]

Any clues ?

Comment: I am also seeing the same behavior. I believe that Portal UI has changed recently. I don't think you can do anything about it.

Comment: Apparently it is as designed - you can vote to revert via this link : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/43689273-azure-portal-tenant-switch-navigation

Comment: @cat5dm The changes you see are the new setting and preferences experience in the portal , documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/set-preferences . However I did share your feedback to our portal team to further review, as I hear more information will update you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

@cat5dm - Apologies for delay in getting back to this thread. Post validation with our internal team below is the update I can share with you.

Post consistent feedback from customers handling many subscriptions , the full screen experience for settings and filters was the design choice taken. The idea was to centralize all settings in one place rather than two. In the meantime, we are directing the old filter icon to the settings so that users would find the new location without having to discover the gear icon . However, we will be eventually removing the filter button from the top and only have the settings gear.

Hope this information helps.  We hope the new experience will be helpful , however if you have any feedback, please let us know. Thank you